# What can be causing an HTML element to be translucent (CSS)?

Tags: css, user-interface, colors, opacity, translucency

I feel like I'm losing my marbles.

I'm adding tooltips to an existing web browser extension via a CSS overlay. The browser happens to be Firefox.

For some reason, the tooltips are displaying as translucent (semi-opaque).  Here is everything I've tried, all put together into one CSS ruleset:

```
#identifier .class:hover::after {
   display: block !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
   z-index: 2147483647 !important;
   color: rgba(255,255,0,1) !important;
   fill: rgba(0,0,0,1) !important;
   background: rgba(0,255,0,1) !important;
   background-blend-mode: normal !important;
   mix-blend-mode: normal !important;
   transform: none !important;
   content: "Tooltip";
}
```

Here is an image of what is displayed (the text in the tooltip is flipped because the parent element is subjected to a transform; I would normally just retransform the tooltip in this case, but I wanted to reduce variables while figuring out this issue).

[image: Example image of unexpectedly translucent tooltip]

Comment: could you share an image of your issue?

Comment: @MarceloF. Excellent idea.   I've just done that.  Thank you for your interest and suggestion.

Comment: May be it's inheriting some blend-mode ?

Comment: Yes, very unusual but you never know... This behaviour looks like blending mode or there's an translucent element over it

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]? This is only the CSS, which by itself doesn't produce the result in your screenshot. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xenhLd9f/

Comment: @vals I thought you figured it out.  I added `mix-blend-mode: normal !important; background-blend-mode: normal !important;` but it had no impact. According to MDN, those are the only supporters of blend-mode.

Comment: @MarceloF. Thanks. See comment to vals above.

Comment: Well, the only way now is to look at the calculated styles of the element, and check them ...  Quite boring, but sometimes there is no other way. Good luck!